# How can I exclude results from elasticsearch based on the contents of a field?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch on AWS to store logs from Cloudfront. I have created a simple query that will give me all entries from the past 24h, sorted from new to old:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "site_name": "some-site" } }
      ],
      "filter": [
        { 
          "range": { 
            "timestamp": {
              "lt": "now",
              "gte": "now-1d"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    { "timestamp": { "order": "desc" } }
  ]
}
```

Now, there a are certain sources (based on the user agent) for which I would like to **exclude** results. So my question boils down to this:

How can I filter out entries from the results when a certain field **contains** a certain string? Or:

`query.filter.where('cs_user_agent').does.not.contain('Some string')`

(This is not real code, obviously.)

I have tried to make sense of the Elasticsearch documentation, but I couldn't find a good example of how to achieve this.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. What I've done is use a Bool Query in combination with a wildcard:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "site_name": "some-site" } }
      ],
      "filter": [
        { 
          "range": { 
            "timestamp": {
              "lt": "now",
              "gte": "now-1d"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        { "wildcard": { "cs_user_agent": "some string*" } }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    { "timestamp": { "order": "desc" } }
  ]
}
```

This basically matches any user agent string containing "some string", and then filters it out (because of the "must_not").

I hope this helps others who run into this problem.

Comment: Is there any other way without using wildcard query ?It seems that it can be slow https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

Comment: ‹hy dont you use match in your must not ?

Comment: @SylvainAttoumani If I try what you suggest, I get the results I don't want to see. Don't quite know why.

Comment: @GirdharSojitra Yes, I saw that too. I did find out that the wildcard string can do without the first *. I'll update the example.

Answer (score 0):

nod.js client version:

```
    const { from, size, value, tagsIdExclude } = req.body;

      const { body } = await elasticWrapper.client.search({
        index: ElasticIndexs.Tags,
        body: {
          from: from,
          size: size,
          query: {
            bool: {
              must: {
                wildcard: {
                  name: {
                    value: `*${value}*`,
                    boost: 1.0,
                    rewrite: 'constant_score',
                  },
                },
              },
              filter: {
                bool: {
                  must_not: [
                    {
                      terms: {
                        id: tagsIdExclude ? tagsIdExclude : [],
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      });
```